# Terraform example for configuring Cloudwatch Events for Lambda Function (Warm Callback Handler)

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

As part of deployment of Lambda Function using terraform i need to create a cloud watch event for warm call back event.

I am able to easily create it from front end but it's difficult for me to create it from back end as input_transformer configuration is needed.

Any example of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below is the configuration that i have used to create cloudwatch event for warm call back with input_transformer.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "flask-apis-cloudwatch-terraform" {
    name = "warm_call_back_flask_apis"
    description = "Keep Warm Callback function for flask-apis"
    schedule_expression = "rate(4 minutes)"
    role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_exec_flask.arn}"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "flask-apis-cloudwatch-terraform-target" {
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.flask-apis-cloudwatch-terraform.name}"
  target_id = "${aws_lambda_function.flask-apis.function_name}"
  arn       = "${aws_lambda_function.flask-apis.arn}"
  input_transformer = {
    input_paths = {"detail-type"="$.detail-type","resources"="$.resources","detail"="$.detail","id"="$.id","source"="$.source","time"="$.time","region"="$.region","version"="$.version","account"="$.account"}

    input_template = <<INPUT_TEMPLATE_EOF
    {
        "time":<time>, 
        "detail-type": <detail-type>, 
        "source": <source>,
        "account": <account>, 
        "region": <region>,
        "detail": <detail>, 
        "version": <version>,
        "resources": <resources>,
        "id": <id>,
        "kwargs": {}
    }
    INPUT_TEMPLATE_EOF
  }

}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_flask-apis" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.flask-apis.arn}"
    principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.flask-apis-cloudwatch-terraform.arn}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `normal string quotes`. Notice that in the AWS console you have to include the quotes around your string too (Refer this [comment](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7280#issuecomment-585938344))

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "main" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.main.name
  target_id = "SNS-alert"
  arn       = module.sns_notification.topic_arn

  input_transformer {
    input_paths {
      reason     = "$.detail.stoppedReason"
      stopCode   = "$.detail.stopCode"
      clusterARN = "$.detail.clusterArn"
    }

    input_template = "\"Your ECS cluster <clusterARN> was stopped unexpectedly due to '<reason>'. StopCode is <stopCode>.\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use tostring() function as well

```
input_transformer {
input_paths = {
  aws_region = "$.detail.awsRegion",
  aws_account = "$.detail.awsAccountId",
  resource_id = "$.detail.resourceId",
  event = "$.detail.newEvaluationResult.complianceType"
}
input_template = tostring("\"the Resource <resource_type> <resource_id> in AWS account <aws_account>\"")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "repo_event_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.repo_event_rule.name
  target_id = "sns"
  arn       = module.sns_email_topic.arn

  input_transformer {
    input_paths = {
      account_id          = "$.account",
      time                = "$.time",
      region              = "$.region",
      notificationBody    = "$.detail.notificationBody"
    }
    input_template = "\"In your AWS Account '<account_id>' in the region '<region>' at the time '<time>' the following took place: <notificationBody>\""
  }
}
```

This works but does anybody know how I can do line breaks with Terraform? \n Won't work and neither does multi line strings.

Comment: I read from HashiCorp's github repo that the line break is `\\n`

[HashiCorp's Github: specific comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7280#issuecomment-719717999)